# Right approach to solve Maximum Product Subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve this questions:

Given an array that contains both positive and negative integers, find the product of the maximum product subarray.
**Assumption**: There is always a positive product possible, i.e., no array of this form: {0,-20,0,0} or {-20}.

**Example**:

```
6 -3 -10 0 2
ANS = 180

2 3 4 5 -1 0 
ANS = 120

8 -2 -2 0 8 0 -6 -8 -6 -1
ANS = 288
```

**My Solution:**

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // FAILS FOR THIS TEST CASE
    // 9 0 8 -1 -2 -2 6
    arr.add(9);
    arr.add(0);
    arr.add(8);
    arr.add(-1);
    arr.add(-2);
    arr.add(-2);
    arr.add(6);

    int maxEndingHere = 1;
    int minEndingHere = 1;
    int max_so_far = 1;

    for (int k = 0; k < arr.size(); k++) {
      maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere * arr.get(k);
      if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
        minEndingHere = minEndingHere * maxEndingHere;
        if (minEndingHere > 0) {
          maxEndingHere = minEndingHere;
          minEndingHere = 1;
        } else {
          maxEndingHere = 1;
        }
      }

      if (maxEndingHere == 0) {
        maxEndingHere = 1;
        minEndingHere = 1;
      }

      if (max_so_far < maxEndingHere) {
        max_so_far = maxEndingHere;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(max_so_far);
  }
```

My solution fails for the case where the array values are **9 0 8 -1 -2 -2 6**. The correct answer is 24, but I am getting 16. Can someone help me figure out if my approach is wrong?

I have read other solutions to the problem, most of them are a variation of **kadane's algorithm**. I am just trying to figure out if my approach is completely wrong.

Comment: Kadane's algorithm is not applicable here. By the way since the empty array has a product of 1, you don't need any additional assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm fails because when a negative value *a* in the array makes a negative *maxEndingHere* positive, that *a* is never considered again as a possible first value of a new sub sequence.

This is the case with the 3<sup>rd</sup> element (-2) in this sample array (I ignore the 9 0 that precede it):

```
8 -1 -2 -2 6
```

After processing that -2, the algorithm has set *maxEndingHere* to 16, which at that point is the best result so far. But then the algorithm continues with the -2 that follows, and starts a new product (as *minEndingHere* is 1 and becomes -2). The middle -2 is not reused for a possible new sequence where it could play a role. And so the algorithm only finds -2 * 6, and not -2 * -2 * 6.

I would suggest the following algorithm which seems more intuitive and also runs in linear time:

Look at sub sequences that are delimited by 0 values. Then, if the product of these values is positive, it is a candidate. If it is negative, see which of the two following actions yields the highest product:

- remove values from the left side until, and including, the first negative value, and adjust the product accordingly;
- remove values from the right side until, and including, the last negative value, and adjust the product accordingly;

This gives a positive product, and makes it a candidate.

Finally keep track which of the candidates is the greatest product.

Here is the algorithm implemented in simple JavaScript:

```js
function maxProduct(a) {
    var i, j, product, productLeft, productRight, best;
    
    best = 0;
    product = 1;
    productLeft = 0;
    i = 0;
    
    for (j = 0; j <= a.length; j++) { // go one index too far
        if (j == a.length || a[j] == 0) { // end of non-zero sequence
            if (j > i) { // there is at least one value in this sub sequence
                if (product < 0) { // need to remove a negative factor
                    product /= productLeft < productRight // NB: both are negative
                        ? productRight : productLeft; 
                }
                if (product > best) {
                    best = product;
                }
            }
            // reset for next sub sequence
            product = 1;
            productLeft = 0;
            i = j + 1;
        } else {
            product *= a[j];
            if (a[j] < 0) {
                // Keep track of product until first negative value
                if (productLeft == 0) {
                    productLeft = product;
                }
                productRight = 1;
            }
            // Keep track of product from last negative value onwards
            productRight *= a[j]; 
        }
    }
    return best;
}

// Sample data
a = [9, 0, 8, -1, -2, -2, 6];

// Get max product
result = maxProduct(a);

// Output array and result
console.log(a.join(','));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you state the meaning of your variables and step through your code to see when/whether they develop as you expect them to?

I guess your assumption is that after each step the variables maxEH (minEH) should represent the largest positive (smallest negative) product ending at the respective position in the array or 1 if there is no positive (negative) product ending there. So, the assumption would be that the values develop as follows:

- 9 -> (9,1) [as does your code]
- 0 -> (1,1) [same]
- 8 -> (8,1) [same]
- -1 -> (1,-8) [same]
- -2 -> (16,-2) [your code says: (16,1)]
- -2 -> (4,-32) [...ex falso...]
- 6 -> (24,-192)

So, if I was right about your intention, then 
a) <strike>the idea is sound</strike>, b) your code is flawed and c) your code looks too complex. I would suggest to switch on the sign of arr[k] to make things easier.

Adding to a): I am convinced your approach is impossible to implement correctly. Maintaining the minEH/maxEH iteratively will always fail if you have longer sequences of negative numbers (at least, if I correctly guessed your expected invariant). Take -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7. Your maxEh/minEH sequence should be (1/-2), (6,1), (12,-24), (120,-60). Your code not even closely computes these values. Apparently, it broke on the first sequence of negative numbers.